# What's the fastest algorithm to represent a prime as sum of two squares?

Tags: algorithm, math, number-theory

I could use two loops to check for all combinations of two integers that less than `p` prime, but it's very inefficient. Is there a better algorithm to approach this problem? Any idea?

Where `p mod 4 = 1`.

Thanks,

Comment: Try asking in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @sinelaw: Hi, I don't think this type of question suits that site, since from my understanding, `cstheory` is for research level. Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `p = 1 mod 4`.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29644/enumerating-ways-to-decompose-an-integer-into-the-sum-of-two-squares Might be of some use.

Comment: @vlad OP means p mod 4 = 1, now corrected

Comment: @vlad: I used congruence notation. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Chan: IIRC we wrote `p == 1 (mod 4)` at my uni, which probably also makes things easier for non-mathematicians to read. Where `==` is the best ascii representation of what we actually wrote, which was an &equiv; character when it was necessary to be pedantic, or just `=` if it's obvious and you're lazy. Or if you've formally declared that you're working entirely in the ring of integers modulo 4, of course, but that wouldn't lead to very interesting decompositions into sum of two squares...

Comment: `p=1 (mod 4)` is perfectly clear, at least to my eyes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using the [Hermite-Serret](http://www.numbertheory.org/courses/MP313/lectures/lecture13/page4.html) algorithm.

You can also find a good list of algorithms on this math.se page: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/efficiently-finding-two-squares-which-sum-to-a-prime

See especially, Robin Chapman's answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/efficiently-finding-two-squares-which-sum-to-a-prime/5883#5883

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to search for all combinations.  A rough outline of a simple naive implementation would be:

- Consider each integer i in the range [1..trunc(sqrt(p))].
- Calculate sqrt(p-i^2) and check if it is an integer. If so you are done.
- If not continue to the next i.

Would this suffice for your needs?  It will work fine for relatively small p, but obviously would be slow for the sort of large primes used in cryptography.

Comment: `p-i^2` will always be an integer.  I think you want `sqrt(p-i^2)`

Answer (score 0):

Well I could recommended you reread [Fermat's 4n+1 Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fermats4nPlus1Theorem.html).

If software engineers use right tools for the job, thy have simple solutions. My Mathematica function:

```
P[p_] := Reduce[-p + x^2 + y^2 == 0, {x, y}, Integers]
```

#### Examples:

Finding solutions for first few primes p which are 1 or 2 (mod 4).

```
P /@ {2, 5, 13, 17, 29, 37, 41, 53, 61}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a means of getting an answer, but it's not an algorithm.

Comment: @Steve Jessop Algorithm is a set of instructions, that combine to accomplish a task. You can say, I defined my algorithm in bottom-up approach, assuming `Reduce` function exists - and in fact, I did not need anything else (it's art of building a query). `Reduce[expr, vars, dom]` function reduces the statement `expr` by solving equations or inequalities for `vars` and eliminating quantifiers  over the domain dom.

Comment: @Margus: that's not a correct definition of "algorithm", and an algorithm is not just any set of instructions. Your instructions rely on the existence of a tool (Mathematica) which already solves the problem. Perhaps by the brute force method the questioner already mentions, perhaps by a cleverer method. Either way, "just use Mathematica" might be good advice but it does *not* yield an algorithm. If you took the lid off Mathematica and explained how it actually solves this problem, then that would yield an algorithm.

Comment: Or put it another way: "copy the answer of the smartest person in your class". Is that an algorithm? No, because it's not reasonable to admit the smartest person in your class into the set of tools which can be assumed for this task. I'd say the same for Mathematica, since the question is clearly elementary whereas Mathematica solves it in a single opaque step. If the question were "what's the best algorithm for multiplying two 4-digit numbers", then likewise we'd rule C's multiplication operator out of the available algorithmic steps.

Comment: @Margus: it still might be the fastest way for the questioner to get what he wants. Just depends why he's asking.